# Partition 2d array in sub-arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have to partition a 2d array (the size is given by the user) into sub-arrays given an input number by the user. The code i Wrote works well for most of the instances by there are some that I need some help with.

I do this by taking the square root of the input number. So for example:
If the user inserts [10, 10, 9] it means that this is a 10 * 10 array with 9 sub-arrays. Taking the square root of 9 works fine because it gives 3.
If the user inserts [8, 6, 6] it takes the square root of 6 and rounds it up for the longest side (which gives 3) and rounds it down for the shortest (which is 2). So 3 * 2 = 6. It also works fine.

Then there is a situation like 8. The square root of 8 gives 3 and 2. So the array is partitioned into 6 sub-arrays. Is there another way to find a better partitioning for numbers like 8, 14? Or is there a way to find the optimal distribution for such numbers (e.g. 2 * 4 = 8, 2 * 7 = 14)?

Comment: Can you explain how you divide subarrays? For example does  [10,10,9] gives out 9 subarrays that are 3x3?

Comment: Yes exactly. 9 gives a 3 * 3 array. In the second example [8, 6, 6] it gives a 3 * 2 array.

Comment: The problem needs further qualification; what is the desired result if the number of desired sub-arrays is larger than the number of total elements, e.g. `[3,3,1000]`?

Comment: It will simply ask the user for a better input. I don't think that this is our problem for now.

Comment: I can't understand anything!

Comment: Can those subarray overlap??

Comment: No it's not a cam (?) problem. Also it's not my problem that you cannot understand. No they must not overlap. It's simple. Just partition an array into subarrays. That's all. No special requirements.

Comment: If I understand correctly: Input of 12 -> 3 * 4 (and not 2 * 6); input of 21 -> 3 * 7; input of 24 -> 4 * 6 (and not 3 * 8 or 2 * 12); etc. Or the first square root: 12 -> 16 [4 by 4]; 21 -> 25 [5 by 5]; 24 -> 25 [5 by 5]?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate them a bit different way:

```
int x = Math.round(Math.sqrt(n));
int y = Math.round(1. * n / x);
```

Thus you'll receive:

```
n = 8  => x = 3, y = 3
n = 14 => x = 4, y = 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already had tested Math.round. I will test your way for y. Why did you put 1. before n/x?

Comment: to make this expression of double type - the same as ((double) n) / x

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is find the two nearest factors to the square root. Try this code:

```
long n = 14;

long y = 0;
long x = Math.round(Math.sqrt(n));
while(true){
    if (n % x == 0) {
        y = n/x;
        break;
    }
    else {
        x--;
    }
}
```

You might also like to put in some error checking to cope with input errors. e.g. n<1.